# query con parametros como puedo concatenar los parametros?

Tags: vb.net, vb

tengo esto pero quiero concatener los parametros en una sola columna

```html
    Dim query As String = "UPDATE DEPARTAMENTO set DESCRIPCION= @pais & @ciudad WHERE FOLIO=1"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, cn)
    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pais", dspais)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ciudad", dsciudad)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

como puedo concatenarlos? @pais & @ciudad

Answer (score 1):

En sql se pueden concatenar cadenas Varchar con el signo de `+`, y también hay una función `CONCAT(P1,P2)`, con cualquiera de las dos te debe funcionar.

```
Dim query As String = "UPDATE DEPARTAMENTO set DESCRIPCION= @pais + @ciudad WHERE FOLIO=1"
```

Y también SQL

```
Dim query As String = "UPDATE DEPARTAMENTO set DESCRIPCION= CONCAT(@pais, @ciudad) WHERE FOLIO=1"
```

[SQL Server CONCAT() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_concat.asp)